# correct video brightness in selection

Tags: blender, video-editing

I made a video of a conference talk but the speaker is quite dark and the presentation is perfectly bright as the camera was adjusted to the presentation area. How can I correct the brightness of the speaker, while not changing the brightness of the presentation area? I guess I have to make some kind of selection of the area I want to correct, but I don't know how to do this with e.g. Blender or Openshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a [mask](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/movie_clip_editor/masking/introduction.html) that defines the area to be adjusted.

In some situations, such using a [blue screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) you can automate the selection of the background. Other times you might use [motion tracking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/movie_clip_editor/introduction.html) to have a shape follow the surrounding video or you can manually keyframe the change of position of the mask so that it follows something in the video.

Once the mask has been defined, you can either use the sequencer or the compositor to adjust the area as you want.

With the sequencer, a mask modifier can be combined with one or more of the available [modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/properties/modifiers.html) to adjust a portion of a strip.

[image: VSE strip modifiers]

Using [the compositor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/introduction.html) a [mask](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/input/mask.html) is connected to other nodes to control what area they affect. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3df4Lxchf4Q) shows using a mask with the compositor.

I'm not familiar with openshot but expect it will offer similar masking features as blender. If you need help using blender ask at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. After a lot of googling and youtube tutorials I finally made it work by using masks!